# Prolog: difference between var, nonvar and ground

Tags: prolog

In Prolog, especially in it's metaprogramming aspects, people often talk about **ground** and **non-ground** variables. As well as using predicates such as **var/1**, **nonvar/1** and **ground/1**. But what exactly is the distincion between them?

My current understanding is the following:

- A **var** is completely uninstantiated (eg. X)
- A **nonvar** is instantiated, but might contain some variables deeper down (eg. term(1,2,Y)). This is similar to a weak head normal form from Haskell.
- A **ground var** is completely instantiated, all the way down (eg. term(1,2,3)).

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct. Just be aware that e.g. `X = a, ground(X)` succeeds but `ground(X), X = a` fails. In other words, the metalogical predicates give you information about the instantiation status of the term in the current derivation (under the current answer substitution), not the syntactic structure of its argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly.

- If `var(X)` then variable `X` designates something that is uninstantiated, a "hole". `X` is a "fresh variable". *Note: That predicate should really be named `fresh(...)`. Whether `X` is a variable is actually a question about the program text. But what we want to know is whether what is in between the parentheses is a **fresh** variable (at the moment that call is made, because, quite non-logically, that can change.)*
- `nonvar(X)` is just the complement of `var(X)`, same as `\+ var(X)`. Whatever is between the parentheses designates something (if it is a variable) or *is* something (if it is a non-variable term, as in `nonvar(foo)`) that is not a "hole".
- `ground(X)` means that whatever is between the parenthese designates something or is something that has no holes in its structure (in effect, no holes at the term's leaves).

Some test code. I expected the compiler to issue more warnings than it did.

```
:- begin_tests(var_nonvar).

% Amazingly, the compiler does not warn about the code below.

test("var(duh) is always false", fail) :-
  var(duh). 

% Amazingly, the compiler does not warn about the code below.

test("var(X) is true if X is a fresh variable (X designates a 'hole')") :-
   var(_). 

% Compiler warning: " Singleton variable, Test is always true: var(X)"

test("var(X) is true if X is a fresh variable (X designates a 'hole')") :-
   var(X). 
   
% The hole designated by X is filled with f(_), which has its own hole.
% the result is nonvar (and also nonground)

test("var(X) maybe true but become false as computation progresses") :-
   var(X),X=f(_),nonvar(X).
   
test("var(X) is false otherwise") :-
   var(_).   

% The hole is designated by an anonymous variable

test("a fresh variable is not ground, it designates a 'hole'", fail) :-
   ground(_). 
   
% Both hhe holes are designated by anonymous variables

test("a structure with 'holes' at the leaves is non-ground", fail) :-
   ground(f(_,_)). 
   
test("a structure with no 'holes' is ground") :-
   ground(f(x,y)).

test("a structure with no 'holes' is ground, take 2") :-
   X=f(x,y), ground(X).
   
% var/1 or ground/1 are questions about the state of computation,
% not about any problem in logic that one models. For example:

test("a structure that is non-ground can be filled as computation progresses") :-
   K=f(X,Y), \+ ground(f(X,Y)), X=x, Y=y, ground(f(X,Y)).
   
:- end_tests(var_nonvar).
```

Comment: Why the insistence on fresh? `X = Y, var(Y).` succeeds although Y is an alias for `Y` and occurs earlier in the query.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x It's a personal thing. "Earlier in the query" (or rather, the goal) is not really important. In an ideal world, Prolog would rearrange the elements of a goal to find a "best way to resolve the constraints between the variables" - so what's really important is "earlier in the processing" or just "as yet uninitialized", hence "fresh", which is a good word as any.

Comment: But that's what I meant: `X` is not an Eigenvariable or we would be able to introduce a quantifier. But `X = Y ∧ var(Y)` is not equivalent to `X = Y ∧ ∀Z var(Z)`. (Besides `var/1` is an extra-logical predicate anyway, it doesn't respect commutativity of conjunction).

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Well, yes. Prolog is not really really about logical formulas. var(X) doesn't even make sense in (at least classical) logic. But ... why worry about this?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer The logic discussion is a distraction, but the original point stands: The query `X = Y, var(X), var(Y)` succeeds. Yet at least one of `X` or `Y` is not "fresh", nor "as yet uninitialized", nor even "unbound", at the times the `var/1` calls are made.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie is it useful to consider both X and Y as variables not "filled" by content? Both are "null" and all X=Y does is equate them such that whenever X or Y are given values, either X or Y will point to that value? In contrast X=Y, X=3, var(Y) reports false, as expected.

Comment: @Penelope yes this notion can be useful. `var(X)` corresponds to the statement that `X` is not "filled" in this sense. `nonvar(X)` would mean that it is "filled" at least partly, i.e., it is bound to a term, but that term may still contain "unfilled" variables. `ground(X)` means that `X` is bound to a term that does not contain any "unfilled" variables.