# How to solve equations with negation in prolog

Tags: prolog

I've tried to solve a simple problem in prolog: choose an object which is green but isn't round shape. So I wrote this code:

```prolog
is_good(Item) :-
    not(round(Item)),
    green(Item).

round(melon).
round(umbrella).
round(ball).

green(melon).
green(bow).
```

Trying to solve this, I got:

```prolog
is_good(bow).
true        %% "bow" is the correct answer
is_good(melon).
false
is_good(X). %% Here we trying to find an appropriate item
false       %% and fail
```

So, there is one solution, but we have to check it manually.
But when I changed code to this (no negation):

```prolog
is_good(Item) :-
    round(Item),
    green(Item).

round(melon).
round(umbrella).
round(ball).

green(melon).
green(bow).
```

All works perfectly fine:

```prolog
is_good(bow).
false
is_good(melon).
true            %% "melon" is the correct answer
is_good(X).     %% Here we trying to find an appropriate item
X = melon       %% and success
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply need to [instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63456244/prolog-difference-between-var-nonvar-and-ground) the variable first:

```
?- green(Item), \+ round(Item).
Item = bow.
```

Comment: Thank you, after to this

`
is_good(Item) :-
    green(Item), not(round(Item)).
`

all became fine.